# Java Class With Same Package Name As Other Class

Tags: java, security

I have two directories in a source tree.

The first directory has a package hierarchy that contains a class with matching package name and has package visibility.

The second directory has the same package hierarchy as the first directory that contains a class with the same package name and has main method that use the class in the first directory tree.

I compiled the class *.java file in the first directory tree and has a .class file in the same directory as the *.java file.

I then set classpath variable in command prompt to add the first directory absolute path to the variable.

I compiled the class *.java file in the second directory tree and has *.class file in the same directory as the *.java file.

I then execute the *.class file in the second directory tree and it executed successfully.

If the class in the first directory tree is from a third party, then this is a security risk because users of the third party *.jar files can access the java package visibility classes in the jar files by using the same package name as the classes.

Comment: Please consider writing an example. Some small snippets of code that show what you've just explained. I'm sorry, but I just don't understand what you're trying to get at.